How can I read large file CSV file up 500 GB in Apache Spark and perform aggregation on it?
How can I read large file CSV file up 500 GB in Apache Spark and perform calculation and transformation on one of its Column. I have been given a large file to perform ETL and calculation on it. I am newbie in Python / Spark. Any help will be appreciated
Try to read the file and applied formula but its taking too much time.

CSV is not best format for spark processing. In your example there is not much you can do to optimise it.
If you have 1 big csv file (500GB) it cannot be read by multiple executors in parallel, also csv is not column oriented file structure, it does not support read only required columns.
Optimisation can be done on input itself:

Cosider splitting input csv to multiple smaller files. This way it can be read by multiple executors in parallel
Consider changing input file format to column oriented file structure. E.g. parquet.


https://garrens.com/blog/2017/10/09/spark-file-format-showdown-csv-vs-json-vs-parquet/#:~:text=*%20CSV%20is%20splittable%20when%20it,indexed%20to%20be%20splittable!)

There are many spark configurations and optimization steps which you can take on to speed up overall processing time.

Compress input output data in order to save time (Use Paraquat Format its optimized for large processing).
Try reading Only necessary columns.
Applying filters can also reduce time
Try to enable the Apache Arrow (this will speed it up) - aka Arrow Optimization
In config set this property spark.sql.execution.arrow.enabled value to true.
Cache your data

